# How to view Azure Service Principal Group Memberships in Azure AD?

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory

I can't find a way to view all the group memberships of a service principal in Azure. I can of course see the service principal in the list of "Direct Members" from the perspective of the group.

For example:

```
myGroup123 has members -> Rob, John, and servicePrincipal9

If I look at "servicePrincipal9", I can't see that it is a member of "myGroup123"
```

Is there a way to find this info in the Portal? Via powershell? Via CLI?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Powershell approach via a MSFT support engineer:

```
Get-AzureADServicePrincipalMembership -ObjectId <String> [-All <Boolean>]
```

Documentation: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/azuread/get-azureadserviceprincipalmembership?view=azureadps-2.0

Answer (score 1):

Get the group membership of a group for a service principal

```
$Groups = New-Object Microsoft.Open.AzureAD.Model.GroupIdsForMembershipCheck
$Groups.GroupIds = (Get-AzureADGroup -Top 1).ObjectId
$SPId = (Get-AzureADServicePrincipal -Top 1).ObjectId
Select-AzureADGroupIdsServicePrincipalIsMemberOf -ObjectId $SPId -GroupIdsForMembershipCheck $Groups

OdataMetadata                                                                                   Value
-------------                                                                                   -----
https://graph.windows.net/85b5ff1e-0402-400c-9e3c-0f9e965325d1/$metadata#Collection(Edm.String) {093fc0e2-1d6e-4a1b-9bf8-effa0196f1f7}
```

Kindly go through the [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/azuread/select-azureadgroupidsserviceprincipalismemberof?view=azureadps-2.0) and check if it helps.

Get the groups and directory roles that this servicePrincipal is a member of. This operation is transitive and will include all groups that this service principal is a nested member of from the following [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/serviceprincipal-list-transitivememberof?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http)

Get the groups and directory roles that this servicePrincipal is a direct member of. This operation is not transitive. Check this [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/serviceprincipal-list-memberof?view=graph-rest-beta&tabs=http)

Comment: I have changed the answer and kindly check if the above one helps.

Comment: given a list of groups, this powershell command checks if the service principal is a member. Not exactly what I'm looking for but still helpful

Comment: the Graph API that you've linked to looks to do the trick - thanks for that!